# devise registration customization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm doing a multi-step signup process. I'm storing the values on `session`. and on the last step, I want to call the `DeviseRegistration#create`. I already have the `devise_scope` configured properly and I can receive the call on the `DeviseRegsitration#create` method.

The main problem I've is that it uses the params submitted on the POST request and not the ones on my `session` var.

I've tried things like:

```
request.params = ActionController::Parameters.new session[:registration_params]
```

I've read the `ActionDispatcher` class but I'm not able to identify how I can do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize devise controllers. As documented in [the wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Tool:-Generate-and-customize-controllers):

```
rails generate devise:controllers users
```

This generator will add the devise controllers to your project. You can modify the controllers you need as per your requirements by directly editing the source code.

Answer (score 0):

What I finally did is, on the `create` of my controller that was already extending devise method:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    params["user"] = session[:registration_params]
    session[:registration_params].deep_merge!(user_params)
    @user = User.new session[:registration_params]
    if @user.valid? && last_step
       params["user"] = session[:registration_params] 
       configure_sign_up_params
       super
    end
  end
end
```